# C# Console.WriteLine is not called from a method

Tags: c#, methods, console.writeline

I've just started studying the C#. And bumped into a problem:
When I use the Console.WriteLine in the **Main** method, it works just fine. However, when I try to break the code into methods, the WriteLine does not return anything. (I use Visual Studio to build and compile the project).

The task is to find a final amount of money a person would get when depositing money based on monthly capitalization. I kinda suspect I just messed up some trivial thing, but would still appreciate an explanation :) Thanks

**The code without methods:**

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        //User input
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the initial amount, percentage, and deposit time (months)");
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

        //Separating the input string into substrings
        string[] separated = userInput.Split(' ');

        //Getting the main variables
        double sum1 = double.Parse(separated[0]);
        double oneMonthPercentage = double.Parse(separated[1]) / 1200; //find a montly amount in percent = amount / 12 month / 100 
        double months = double.Parse(separated[2]);
        double initialSum = sum1;


        //Calculation of the final ammount
        for (int i = 1; i <= months; i++)
        {
            sum1 += sum1 * oneMonthPercentage;
        }

        //Output
        Console.WriteLine("Ammount: " + initialSum);
        Console.WriteLine("Percentage: " + oneMonthPercentage * 1200 + "%");
        Console.WriteLine("Time: " + months);
        Console.WriteLine("Final amount: " + Math.Round(sum1, 2));

    }
}
```

OUTPUTS - [no_methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUOum.jpg)

**The code with methods (WriteLine does not work):**

```
using System;

class Program
{ 
    static void Main()
    {
        //User input
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the initial amount, percentage, and deposit time (months)");
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    //Separating string into substrings
    public static string[] SeparateString(string userInput)
    {
        string[] separated = userInput.Split(' ');
        return separated;
    }

    //calculating the final amount at the end of deposit time
    public static double Calculate(string userInput)
    {

        // defining main variables for calculation

        double sum1 = double.Parse(SeparateString(userInput)[0]);
        double oneMonthPercentage = double.Parse(SeparateString(userInput)[1]) / 1200;
        double months = double.Parse(SeparateString(userInput)[2]);
        double initialSum = sum1;

        //calculation as to the formula 
        for (int i = 1; i <= months; i++)
        {
            sum1 += sum1 * oneMonthPercentage;
        }

        //Output
        Console.WriteLine("Ammount: " + initialSum);
        Console.WriteLine("Percentage: " + oneMonthPercentage * 1200 + "%");
        Console.WriteLine("Time: " + months);
        Console.WriteLine("Final amount: " + Math.Round(sum1, 2));

        return sum1;
    }
}
```

OUTPUTS - [with_methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARDKG.jpg)

Comment: You do not call Calculate from anywhere. You need to call Calculate from the Main method.

Comment: Basic 101 C# programming: A running code, when reaches the closing braces of a method, returns to whoever called that method. It doesn't continue executing the next method and then the next one. You should _drive_ your code in some way

Comment: you need to really learn more about local variables and how to call methods , the code executed when you run the console is only the code included in the main anything not called in the main is useless

Comment: `Main`is a special function, which is "magically" called by the system when you run the program. all the other functions are not. Your code has to call the `Calculate` method in order to run it

Answer (score 4):

You need to call those methods to make them work. Right now you are only calling the initial WriteLine and ReadLine

Answer (score 3):

You don't call any method. You should call `Calculate()` method:

```
static void Main()
{
    //User input
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the initial amount, percentage, and deposit time (months)");
    string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    var result = Calculate(userInput); // call here
}
```